# Android: Can't type in an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I don't know why but I can't type/write on the EditText when I try to do it. 
The EditText's cursor doesn't appear and the keyboard when appears is not the numeric one.
I have the following part of code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.android.asminhasdespesas.Meta_1Activity">


    <TextView android:text="Test:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow>


            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editTextMeta"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text="€"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </TableRow>


        <TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonNaoColocar"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onClick"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonOk"
                android:text="Ok"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onClick"/>

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to solve this situation with **"android:cursorVisible="true"** or even **"android:textColor="#000000"**, I also tried **"android:focusable="true"**
**"android:focusableInTouchMode="true""** but the problem persists, I can't type on EditText.

Can you please help me?

Comment: The code you gave should be fine. It could be caused by something above...

Comment: Are you doing anything with it in your Java files?

Comment: I think the edit text size is too small to click on. It has no text content and has wrap_content set for both width and height. For testing sake, try setting the width and height of the edit text to 100dp and see if it still doesn't work.

Comment: @mkorcha, on my Java files I'm doing this:

EditText meta_editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMeta);
int meta= Integer.parseInt(meta_editText.getText().toString());

Comment: @CurlyCorvus I have also tried it, the behaviour is the same :\

Comment: Copied the entire example into an empty activity and it worked. It might be in the code.

Comment: Meet the same issue, I found it random occurs at low api level (around api 19), and do not know why

Answer (score 5):

You probably want something like:

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editTextMeta"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

- Removed weight (unused)

Comment: Setting `focusable` and `focusableInTouchMode` attributes to true worked in my case.

Answer (score 5):

Check if you have a setOnKeyListener wherever you have the edittext and be sure that you return false if you don't need the event, for example:

```
OnKeyListener listener = new OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                //Do something
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Comment: I had this problem, and it was actually my emulator settings. Go to the emulator's desktop and try to type in the edit text there- if it still doesn't work, go to tools/AVD Manager, select your emulator, click Advanced Settings, and check the "enable Keyboard input".

Comment: Thanks man saved me from several hours of debugging :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm new to the field of **Android Development**. Well, I was facing the same problem. So I just set

```
android:text=""
```

this caused the text to appear when I typed it in the `EditText`. I am not sure why did this work, but I am just speaking from personal experience

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.... Please, [read this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to improove your answers. While what you wrotte could potentially fix the problem, it is just setting the default field value to empty. The issue at hand is still unclear. This site works best, when you can explain to the `Questioning User` ways to solve a problem, documents to read and understand what is causing the issue, or even suggestions on how to improove his code (You will be granted comment permissions later on). Do not answer questions by "I dunno", "here, try this" nor "my stuff works"

Comment: Hhhhhhmmmm, if an answer potentially fixes the problem I would personally find it useful to see. It may not end up being the best possible but the option is always open for the question writer to seek out the knowledge on their own (in this case my personal interest is sparked by the combination of answer and response here). Though at the same time I do understand that best practice is to accompany an answer with some additional explanation, so I see your point Bonatti and thank you for taking the time out to help a new user this way. I wonder if there's precedent in Meta regarding this one...

Comment: Thank you Bonatti as well as Peter for your valuable comments. I will surely try and answer in more detail next time

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter I agree!!!  This helped me, i'm glad it was here. People just need to calm down on the SO authority!  some of us have day jobs.

Comment: @Bonatti it's spelled improve not improove.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue then i removed android:focusableInTouchMode="true" from parent view(LinearLayout) of editbox and its working fine

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the code you have above looks like it wouldn't cause a problem. That leads me to think when you're making the object in your java file(s) you might be screwing with a setting. I would text where the problem stems from by eliminating a lot of the tags from your edit text field, and make it as minimal as possible such as

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:id="@+id/editTextMeta"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using virtual device then just simply wipe data and try again. it will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34903938)